# Rails generate scaffold from migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, rails-migrations

I created a Rails 4 migration file using:

```
rails g migration CreateCompanyAndAttributes
```

I edited the migration to be:

```
def change

  create_table :companies do |c|
    c.integer :name
    c.string :logo_url
    c.timestamps
  end

  create_table :attributes do |a|
    a.string :name
    a.string :description
    a.string :image
    a.timestamps
  end

  create_table :company_attributes do |t|
    t.integer :facility_id
    t.integer :attribute_id
    t.timestamps
  end

end
```

Now that my migration is ready to be deployed, how can I generate scaffold for all three soon to be created tables?

Should I first run:

```
rake db:migrate
```

Then something like

```
rails g scaffold companies
rails g scaffold attributes
rails g scaffold companies_attributes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was not able to find an answer to my original question starting with a migration file, I ended up deleting the migration file and used separate rails generate scaffold command line commands for each table.

```
rails g scaffold Company name:string logo_url:string
rails g scaffold Attribute name:string description:string image:string
rails g scaffold CompanyAttribute company_id:integer attribute_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you want to have the scaffold without the migration (you have already done it manually)

You can run the scaffold command with Use the --skip-migration flag. For example:

```
rails g scaffold Company name:string logo_url:string --skip-migration
```

Hope it meets your need! :)